# I've been trying to add text wrap to my edittext, and nothing looks right

Tags: android, xml

Ok, let me give you some context. I'm making a messaging application (you can tell from my other posts) and right now I'm working on a function to edit your messages. The dialog that shows up has an enter button, but my message box doesn't, it has a "Done" button. I set the imeOptions of that text box to have an enter button and configured some other properties to make it work.

But for some reason, nothing looks polished. I've tried looking at other StackOverflow posts, looking at Google, changing my drawables (which I use for the background of my edittext) but it doesn't look as I expected. I expect the edittext to be at a fixed height once the message box reaches 4 or so lines, and for the attachment icon to always stay in the same location, not expand the height.

Here is my ChatActivity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".chats.ChatActivity"
    android:background="?attr/bgColor"
>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llProgress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSendChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/gray_circle"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="3dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etMessage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/gray_circle"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/enter_message"
                android:imeOptions="actionNone"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textColor="?attr/messageEditTextColor"
                android:textColorHint="?attr/hintTextColor"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivAttachment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:tint="?attr/messageEditAttachmentTint"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_attachment" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivSend"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/red_circle"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:tint="?attr/sendButtonIconColor"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_send"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/srlMessages"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/llSendChat"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/llProgress">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvMessages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: explain in short the exact thing that you want. Try to be more specific.

Comment: The text box in whatsapp, it has a fixed height once it reaches multiple lines, the attachment icon is pinned to the same location, and more. https://prnt.sc/u2wcid

Comment: fixed height: you can set it my setting maxLines: 5 or anything....

Comment: make only this change in your edittext with maxLines attr. and let me know if not working then

Comment: Welcome...hv posted an answer for the same. pls accept & upvote if found useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set max lines in EditText:

```
android:maxLines="5"
```

or any number instead of 5.

Comment: was this helpful ??

Comment: Yes, it was! It worked. What about the attachment icon? My attachment icon's height always stretches to the height of the edittext. Refer to this screenshot from WhatsApp, and look at the screenshot icon: https://prnt.sc/u2wcid

Comment: set height to 10dp or 5dp of the icon instead of wrap_content.

Comment: No, it's a problem with the height. The height of the attachment icon is match_parent, so it looks right when there is only one line in the textview, but I don't know what to do so it looks right when there are more than one line. It should always stay in the same place, no matter how many lines there are.